# Dealing with escape characters in hive (Regexp_replace)

Tags: mapreduce, hive, regexp-replace

We are facing with a performance issue in processing of escape characters while the data processeing at the time of loading in through hive query.

```
if (data.contains("\"")|data.contains("\b")|data.contains("\f")|        data.contains("\n")|data.contains("\r")|
        data.contains("\t")|
        data.contains("\"")|
        data.contains("|")
    ) 
{                                
    if (data.contains("\b")) 
        data = data.replace("\b", "\\b");

    if (data.contains("\f")) 
        data = data.replace("\f", "\\f");

    if (data.contains("\n")) 
        data = data.replace("\n", "\\n");

    if (data.contains("\r")) 
        data = data.replace("\r", "\\r");

    if (data.contains("\t")) 
        data = data.replace("\t", "\\t");

    if (data.contains("\"")) 
        data = data.replace("\"", "\\\"");

    data = "\""+data+"\"";
```

Here we want to use any function is HIVE to process the data. Tried regexp_replace ..but not getting the exact one to do so...
Pleasee suggest.